# Relative paths angular2. Diffrent paths for template and css

Tags: angular, relative-path

I'm now with last version of angular - 2.0.3.
How to deal with different paths. For example html template is in the same folder, nut css file is in other.

```
@Component({    
selector: "order",
templateUrl: "./app/order/order.template.html",
styleUrls: ["./app/assets/css/order.css"]
})
```

If i will type module.id then will be found just html file. 
Anybody faced with some kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's possible but to me the best practice is to put your component css within the component it's more organized. However,

Just open your `tsconfig.json`  and then change

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

to

```
"moduleResolution": "classic",
```

then you can have

sample structure

```
app
----components
--------order
--------------order.component.ts
--------------order.component.html
assets
----order.css

@Component({
  selector: 'selector',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls:['../../../assets/order.css']  
})
```

it's tested with Angular-cli and webpack version.

Answer (score 0):

This posting helps: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html

I am using **SystemJS**, so in my `tsconfig.json`, I set `"module": "system"`.

I also added `moduleId: __moduleName` into my `@Component`.

Then I can use relative path for template and style. For example:

`@Component({
    selector: 'datepicker-popup',
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    directives: [],
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: './datepicker.comp.html',
    styleUrls: ['./datepicker.css']
})`

Comment: Thought you are using old version of angular, but there is no difference in this situation. The problem is that css and html file situated in various folders. When you write moduleId angular will look at the folder where are css and html files. That's why your solution doesn't will work.

Comment: I guess you are right. I am using Angular 2 Beta instead of RC

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
selector:'my-app-product',
moduleId:module.id,
templateUrl:'product.component.html',
styleUrls: ['product.component.css']
```

and put your `product.component.css` file within the same folder as html file